# font-lock problem of c++ mode

Tags: major-mode, font-lock, c++

I recently notice that there's some strange behaviours of the font-lock of the c++-mode.

Let's start emacs by `emacs -Q` in the terminal, edit a new file `test.cpp` and save the following contents

[image]

Then put the cursor two lines above the `int main` line, type `int test`, you will find that the color of word `main` changes from *blue* to *black*

[image]

Backspace the current line to `in` or `i`, you will see that the color of `main` change back to *blue*.

This is not a very big problem under this test, but I use color theme that the function names are in *bold* type. So when I add a function above another function, the font-lock of the below one keep changing all the time which is really annoying.

Is this a emacs bug ? I want *bold* function name and other keywords but how can I get rid of it ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could mitigate the problem by first inserting a semicolon for function declarations or curly braces for function definition and then start typing your function before them. A good way would be to use templates to define functions, e.g. by using yasnippet: `f` `M-x yas-expand`.

Comment: @theldoria This is not only happens when adding a new function. when one type 'std::out' above another 'std::out', the font-lock is also keep changing.

Comment: Well, again, first put a semicolon and put whatever you want before that. You could, for example, bind the following function to `M-;`: `(defun my-semicolon ()
  "Insert semicolon and puts cursor before that"
  (interactive)
  (insert ";")
  (backward-char 1))`.